# Как задать cmake нужный компилятор?

Tags: cmake, clang

Как заставить `cmake` использовать компилятор `clang`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Имя компилятора (ищется в `$PATH`), либо полный путь до него задаётся в переменных `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` (для исходников на Си) и `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` (для исходников на C++).

Задать значение этих переменных (впрочем, как и любых других) можно одним из как минимум двух способов:

- либо через командную строку при вызове CMake:

  ```
  cmake -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:STRING="путь/до/компилятора"
  cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:STRING="путь/до/компилятора"
  ```
- либо через модификацию `CMakeLists.txt`:

  ```
  SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER путь/до/компилятора)
  SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER путь/до/компилятора)
  ```

Comment: Спасибо. Заодно не подскажите хороший туториал по `сmake` для новичка?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, э... Даже не знаю. Ну, например, «[Введение в CMake](https://habrahabr.ru/post/155467/)» на Хабрахабре. Если же вы используете Qt, то будет ещё полезно почитать «[Использование CMake с Qt 5](https://habrahabr.ru/post/181838/)» и «[CMake Manual](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/cmake-manual.html)».